# Force Reload Table View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

All,

How would I force reload a table view (within a view controller) every five seconds for fifteen seconds when a button is pressed?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you create a timer when you press your button,

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then in your method that fires every 5 seconds

```
- (void) updateMethod
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out `NSTimers` & Apple [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).  This will give you a concept about intervals and help you with the delay you are looking for.

And for reloading tableview, `[self.tableView reloadData];` should to the trick.