# Uploading Progress bar in menu bar - osx application

Tags: objective-c, macos, progress-bar

I would like to implement the progress with floating from 0% to 100 % and the estimation of upload time.
I have tried with the menu bar controller example. But it doesn't help to implement the floating progress bar in the panel view controller.

Please check the below image for my implementation. When i click on (W) icon in menu bar, table is loading and show the upload progress bar. When the uploading is moving to next step. How to reload the table for every 1 sec or 2 sec without the event click.. ? When user click on the icon the progress should move continuously.

Looking forward for ideas or the sample code.

[image]

Comment: I have tried with [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self
                                   selector:@selector(fetchFileArray) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; and NSNotification Default center . . But once the event(Click) occurred i can able to show the uploading bar continuously . . But It doesn't occur automatically in when i'm view the list in NSTable view. .

Comment: Are you talking about Mac or iOS app?

Comment: I'm talking the Mac OSX App. . I have updated the image in question for my implementation. When i click on (W) icon in menu bar, table is loading and show the upload progress bar. When the uploading is moving to next step. How to reload the table for every 1 sec or 2 sec without the event click.. ? When user click on the icon the progress should move continuously. I hope you got it. .

Answer (score 0):

The below link helps to fix the issue :

[Force Reload Table View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767768/force-reload-table-view)

To reload the table view, used NSTimer frequently to update the progress bar.